# QGIS 2.99 "qgis._core import error: DLL load failed"

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I am trying to run a standalone application. However, it does not run the program because of mentioned error in title. Here is my code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QgsApplication([], True)
path = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev"
app.setPrefixPath(path, True)
app.initQgis()

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
title = "PyQGIS Standalone Application Example"
canvas.setWindowTitle(title)
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

layer_info = 'LineString?crs=epsg:4326'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_info, 'MyLine', "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
linstr = QgsFeature()
wkt = "LINESTRING (1 1, 10 15, 40 35)"
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
linstr.setGeometry(geom)
pr.addFeatures([linstr])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayers([layer])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
exitcode = app.exec_()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
sys.exit(exitcode)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/MyMap/myMap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Python version is: 3.6
PyQt   version is: PyQt5.9
Windows 10 - 64bit

I also add many path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\OSGeo4W64
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev\bin
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev\pymod3\Lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\bin
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\bin
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\include
C:\Users\Mustafa Uçar\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default
C:\Users\Mustafa Uçar\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does that help? `path = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-dev"`

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn  
I added all paths that I can add. You can see them in the edited question.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what's wrong. This message normally is a hint that some dlls for python are missing (rather than an error in the script). I'm not very familiar with the setup on Windows, but extrapolating from Linux: There should be a `_core.dll` file in `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis` which is either missing or corrupted.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Yes there is a _core named file but it is not .dll. It is "_core.pyd" file in C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\qgis

Comment: That's not what you are looking for. Can you reinstall/upgrade the qgis-dev-python (might be called slightly different) package in osgeo4w?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I used osgeo4w with advanced install and selected the site-packages manually. Maybe I did not select the neccessary package/packages. Is there any advice about selecting right packages?

Comment: @MustafaUçar Are you by change using eclipse and pydev? I had the same problem when in eclipse.ini I had -vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath. Java must be set with real jre path: -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin\javaw.exe.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working for 3 weeks for this problem. However, I found it finally. I write python console in qgis:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

It gives the path and I paste them into PYTHONPATH and PATH. That's it!

Comment: Could you update your answer by posting the qgis-specific content of your PATH and PYTHONPATH variable maintaining your order of the paths? Unfortunately your approach doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you try this please?PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python;                                                    PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\plugins\processing;

Comment: If the problem continues, let me know

Comment: Thanks for posting the paths but the problem still exists in pydev - eclipse. Despite adding PyQt5 and qgis as forced builtins python throws me the error mentioned in the title of your question. I can't even add/configure the interpreter with your configuration...

Comment: https://ibb.co/gERiCw  here is my variables you can use it. ıf error continues please tell me again