# QGIS MADEIRA - could not load SIP module and qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook error - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis, installation

I updated QGIS Girona to QGIS Madeira and now I have the problem. Every time I open QGIS I get two errors:

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 72, in 
from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 26, in 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by 
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)

Python version:
3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]

QGIS version:
 3.4.0-Madeira 'Madeira', 4a4b62e
```

And I checked, I have QtCore.so on that path. And my version is PyQt5-5.11.3.

Second error:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'qgis' is not defined


Python version:
3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]

QGIS version:
3.4.0-Madeira 'Madeira', 4a4b62e

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python',     '/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

After that I tried to reinstall QGIS - it didn't help, I tried to install back Girona - didn't succeed in that. I tried to reinstall Qt library, also nothing. I tried solutions from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31036/couldnt-load-sip-module) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108458/couldnt-load-sip-module-qgis-doesnt-load-python) - also didn't help.

And at the end. It really doesn't matter which version I would have (only to be 3.X). I needed it to set up PyQGIS with Pycharm.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Comment: If you updated any python modules with pip, uninstall them and take the version from the default Ubuntu repo.

Comment: I reinstalled the system, It was the fastest solution than the all other which I tried.

Comment: But I have done that after few days of trying.

Comment: @Neven you should now have pyqt5-5.10.1, right? Please self-answer your question, for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: No. I have Qt 5.9.5. But I didn't find a solution, a just reinstall system (Ubuntu).
That can do everyone. But I will write that.

Comment: You are right, I mistook versions of python-qt5 and libqt5.

Comment: this does not help at all?
I have same problem
I installed qt5.12 which took me some hours and now stuck with this SIP problem
can anyone give step by step solution please

Comment: I have the answer to this question. You can do that, but it is not elegant and fastest way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of desperately trying, I reinstall Ubuntu18.04 and install QGIS 3.4 Madeira.
Now I have the QT5 library which was came with QGIS, and version is 5.9.5