# Python error when run QGIS **Couldn't load SIP module

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, visual-studio

I am getting error when run QGIS.

```
    **Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.**


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "D:/qgis/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-test-x86_64/output/python\qgis\__init__.py", line 70, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "D:/qgis/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-test-x86_64/output/python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.


Python version:
3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
3.15.0-Master 'Master', 2c1bcffbc8

Python path:
['D:/qgis/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-test-x86_64/output/python', 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python', 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\\profiles\\default/python/plugins', 'D:/qgis/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-test-x86_64/output/python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts', 'D:\\qgis\\QGIS\\ms-windows\\osgeo4w\\build-qgis-test-x86_64\\output\\bin\\RelWithDebInfo\\python37.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib', 'D:\\qgis\\QGIS\\ms-windows\\osgeo4w\\build-qgis-test-x86_64\\output\\bin\\RelWithDebInfo', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

[image]

Does anyone know a fix for this?

This is my environments variables set:

```
 4W_QT_LIBRARIES=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/lib
    ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
    APPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
    CLIENTNAME=KODZO
    CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
    CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
    COMPUTERNAME=WIN-PEJU5OCJR3F
    ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
    FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
    FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
    GDAL_DATA=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev\share\gdal
    GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev\bin\gdalplugins
    HOMEDRIVE=C:
    HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
    LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local
    LOGONSERVER=\\WIN-PEJU5OCJR3F
    MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=16
    O4W_QT_BINARIES=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/bin
    O4W_QT_DOC=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/doc
    O4W_QT_HEADERS=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/include
    O4W_QT_PLUGINS=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/plugins
    O4W_QT_PREFIX=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5
    O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS=C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/translations
    OS=Windows_NT
    OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
    Path=C:\Python37;C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\proj-dev\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\gdal-dev\bin\gdalplugins;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Administrator\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.3\bin;
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
    POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS=1
    POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS=GTiff PNG JPEG GIF XYZ DTED USGSDEM AAIGrid
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=1a05
    ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
    PROJ_LIB=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\proj-dev\share\proj
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
    PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
    PyCharm Community Edition=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.3\bin;
    PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts
    QtMsBuild=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild
    QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\plugins
    QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Qt\qtcreator-4.12.4\bin\plugins\platforms
    SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#63
    SETUPAPI_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\SetupAPI.Lib
    SystemDrive=C:
    SystemRoot=C:\Windows
    TEMP=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2
    TMP=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2
    USERDOMAIN=WIN-PEJU5OCJR3F
    USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=WIN-PEJU5OCJR3F
    USERNAME=Administrator
    USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrator
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
    VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
    VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
    windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108458/couldnt-load-sip-module-qgis-doesnt-load-python

Comment: Hm, do you start QGis with the correct environment? I use a batch-file for that, but with a official binary release. You did compile from source, I bet. Never done this. Do you know oslandias Tutorial: https://oslandia.com/2017/12/20/qgis-3-compiling-on-windows/

Comment: I edit my question with environments variables list